# How do I get buttons to stay contained in the div and expand the div vertically when there is overflow?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using React and JS to create a website, but I've been having some trouble with the search input for some time now and would really appreciate some help.

Whenever there are too many buttons, instead of staying within the div, the buttons overflow out of the search bar. How do I get the div to expand to accommodate all of the buttons and keep the search input at the end?

Here is what it looks like when the buttons overflow:

[image]

**Here's the necessary code**

CSS:

```js
export const SearchBarContainer = styled(motion.div)`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40em;
  height: 3.8em;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 12px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
`;

export const SearchInputContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 4em;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 15px;
`;

export const RequiredIngredients = styled(motion.div)`
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
`;

export const SearchInput = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #12112e;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    &::placeholder {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  &::placeholder {
    color: #bebebe;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  }
`;
```

JS:

```js
 return (
    <SearchBarContainer
      animate={isExpanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}
      variants={containerVariants}
      transition={containerTransition}
      ref={parentRef}
    >
      <SearchInputContainer>
        <SearchIconSpan>
          <SearchIcon />
        </SearchIconSpan>
        {
          <RequiredIngredients
          >
            {ingredients.map((element, index) => {
              return (
                <IngredientsClicked
                  key={index}
                  thumbnailSrc={
                    "https://spoonacular.com/cdn/ingredients_100x100/" +
                    element.image
                  }
                  name={element.name}
                  onClick={() => {
                    removeIngredient(element.name, element.image, index);
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </RequiredIngredients>
        }
        <SearchInput
          placeholder="Enter an ingredient"
          onFocus={expandContainer}
          ref={inputRef}
          value={search}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
        
        .
        .
        .
        
    </SearchBarContainer>
  );
```

Comment: Have you tried the `flex-wrap`property?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I tried that but for some reason, the buttons are placed vertically instead of horizontally (even when I set `flex-direction` to `row`), and the width of the box for the buttons stops halfway before starting a new column.